# Flat file data cleanup with thousands or millions of records

Tags: python, data-cleaning, flat-file

I have a flat file with tabbed delimited data. I have attached images for your reference. There are thousands to millions of records. This flat file has a same header on top and throughout the text file in between the first row and the end of the row but also has different timestamps values. Currently, I have been cleaning these characters manually which is painful. Is there a better way to get these unwanted characters removed and only get the result like in the last image?. Thank You in advance.
Data file received in unclean format

[image]

I would like the file to be cleaned up as follows without any headings
[image]

Comment: This is two commands in a text editor.  Or, on Linux, `grep -v -e "date ran" -e "sales for" -e "CodeNo" infile.txt > outfile.txt`.  On WIndows, `findstr /v /c:"date ran" /c:"sale for" /c:"CodeNo" infile.txt > outfile.txt`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but when i tried to type the findstr in windows search bar dos like command prompt pops up but vanishes when clicked.

Comment: You have to open a command shell of course, and you'll have to change to the directory where the file exists.

Comment: Thanks Tim. There are so many other variation issues with the file that I simply brought the data that was under a million records into excel and cleaned the long text manually. It didn't take long, only few minutes. I will still give you credit for helping out. Thanks